# Help with this problem in number theory

Tags: number-theory

$$xy = z^{2} + 1, (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{N}$$

Prove that there exists integers $$a, b, c, d$$ such that $$x = a^2 + b^2, y = c^2 + d^2, z = ac + bd$$

Could someone give me a hint on how to go about this? I've tried factorising with the equations given and simplifying, but the best I can do is proving with example and can't prove a general case :S

Thanks very much.

Comment: You sure you meant $x=a^2+b^c$?

Comment: No. Thanks for spotting that error

Comment: Are you familiar with Gaussian integers and their unique prime factorization?

Comment: I'm not, no, do you have a good link that I could read up on? :)

Comment: $(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2) = (ac + bd)^2 + (ad - bc)^2$

Comment: @user78416 could you rename the title to something more useful?  Your question's title should be as specific as possible to the problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

Detailed Hint: As **Calvin Lin** has pointed out, the proof of this fact (implicitly) relies on the properties of the [Gaussian Integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer)
, in particular, it uses the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a 
[Unique factorization domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain)

 and has prime elements:

1. $p\in\mathbb{N}$ where $p\equiv 3$(mod 4)
2. $a+bi$, $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $a^2+b^2\equiv 1$(mod 4), and $a^2+b^2$ is a prime number in $\mathbb{N}$
3. $1+2i$ (up to multiplication by units $1,-1,i,-i$)

This effectively gives us an analagous structure to the Gaussian Integers that the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic gives to Natural numbers (allows us to break into 'prime' elements), so we can now consider divisors of the RHS of the equation.

Back to the question, we can express the RHS as $(z-i)(z+i)$, and deduce properties about the prime element divisors of $z-i$ and $z+i$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)
   &= (ac)^2 + (bd)^2 + (ad)^2 + (bc)^2 \\
   &= (a^2 c^2 + 2abcd + b^2 d^2) + (a^2 d^2 - 2abcd + b^2 c^2) \\
   &= (ac+bd)^2 + (ad-bc)^2
\end{align}